# How Facebook implements auto video play feature in android application

Tags: android, facebook, video-streaming

I have checked the auto video play feature in Facebook news feeds. I am working on an android app and want to implement the same feature in my application. I have the same news feeds layout as Facebook use. I have implemented this using Recyclerview.

Can you please suggest how can I implement the same feature in my application as Facebook do.

In my application the videos can be from any sources like the videos may be from youtube, vimeo or other sources. So I want to give support for all of these types of videos.

Thanks a ton in advanced for all your support.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please suggest how can I implement the same feature in my
>   application as Facebook do.

Please check this link: https://medium.com/@v.danylo/implementing-video-playback-in-a-scrolled-list-listview-recyclerview-d04bc2148429#.gq8fk82sn

> In my application the videos can be from any sources like the videos
>   may be from youtube, vimeo or other sources. So I want to give support
>   for all of these types of videos.

About add youtube video player to your application, please check this link and choose the best way for you app: http://mlsdev.com/en/blog/16-three-ways-to-add-youtube-video-to-android-app

And vimeo video, you can try to use #1 in that link, embed webview to android app, please take a look at this example:

```
//Auto playing vimeo videos in Android webview
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

// how plugin is enabled change in API 8
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
  mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
} else {
  mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
}
mWebView.loadUrl("http://player.vimeo.com/video/24577973?player_id=player&autoplay=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&api=1&maxheight=480&maxwidth=800");
```

Source: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/TjWallas/5432924/raw/0d19f303f9fa7469e2fd5a87b21215fbb793d955/AndroidVimeo.java

Comment: I have already checked this library but I am facing an issue in playing other sources videos like youtube or vimeo videos using this library.

Please suggest here how can I play all videos in my application. 

Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: I am already importing Facebook sdk in my application. Can I use some Facebook code to implement the same in my application, so that I can implement the same functionality in my application also.

Comment: Are you able to use it, if there are multiple videos for single raw ? I want to say that can you autoplay video if single row contains more than one video using ViewPager ? At a time only one video visible, should stop when swiping.